# How to upload files in Laravel directly into public folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The server which I'm hosting my website does not support `links` so I cannot run the `php artisan storage:link` to link my storage directory into the public directory. I tried to remake the disk configuration in the **filesystems.php** to directly reference the `public` folder but it didn't seems to work either. Is there a way to upload a file using Laravel libraries directly into the public folder or will I have to use a php method?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can create a new storage disc in `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'public_uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
],
```

And store files like this:

```
if(!Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put($path, $file_content)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Using this method, how can i name the file as wel?

Comment: $path will have to contain the filename of course, but it can also contain one or more sub folders.

Comment: `$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', 'public_uploads');` for using custom name for uploaded files. Here is the doc. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: @sunomad, As you given created another storage disc, but I need to know how file uploading process will do. Can you please update full code for storing files in controller file itself.

Comment: Don't forget to add `'url' => url('uploads'),` too, otherwise `Storage::disk('public_uploads')->url('filename')` will return [`/storage/filename`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-urls) instead of a fully qualified URL.

Comment: Nothing I have done with the storage folder was functioning. Just this example is working for me even though its not the laravel manner. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

You can pass disk to method of `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` class:

```
$file = request()->file('uploadFile');
$file->store('toPath', ['disk' => 'public']);
```

or you can create new Filesystem disk and you can save it to that disk.

You can create a new storage disk in `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'my_files' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/myfiles',
],
```

in controller:

```
$file = request()->file('uploadFile');
$file->store('toPath', ['disk' => 'my_files']);
```

Answer (score 18):

You should try this hopping you have added `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form. Note that the public path (uploadedimages) will be moved to will be your public folder in your project directory and that's where the uploaded images will be.

```
public function store (Request $request) {
  
  $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $request->image->move(public_path('/uploadedimages'), $imageName);

  // then you can save $imageName to the database

}
```

Comment: easiest way. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

inside config/filesystem.php, add this :

```
 'public_uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],
```

and in the controller

```
$file = $request->file("contract");           
$ext = $file->extension();
$filename = $file->storeAs('/contracts/', $contract->title.'.' . $ext,['disk' => 'public_uploads']);
```

Comment: That code is incorrect. Will create a new folder inside of contracts with the name of the contract.

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible is to edit *.env* file:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the fix to this issue , in the `config/filesystem.php` add this line `'default' => 'public',` in my case that fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: change setting in Filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Step 2: in Controller: Store file like this:

```
'indoc_file' => $request->indoc_file->store('app/file'),
```

Step 3: Go to file `.ENV` and change the Config like this:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

After that your file Location will be saved in Project like this:
`Project\public\app\public\app\file`

if you want to download file able do this on your view page:

```
<a href="{{url('/app/public/'.$item->indoc_file)}}" class="btn btn-info" title="ດາວໂຫຼດ"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to every answer there, I would suggest to add another protection layer because it's a public folder.

For every file that you will have in your public folder that requires protection, do a route that will verify access to them, like

`/files/images/cat.jpg`

and route that looks like `/files/images/{image_name}` so you could verify the user against given file.

After a correct validation you just do
`return response($full_server_filepath, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');`

It makes a work little harder, but much safer

Comment: If a file needs protection, why would you store it in the public folder?

Comment: If a file needs protection, why would you store it in the storage folder? The only difference is that files in public folder are by default open in opposite to storage location. This mean that you will still need to write the access layer for a files no matter what location you choose.

Comment: Sounds like bad design practice to me, like storing models in a controller folder, or javascript files in a css folder. The public folder is meant to hold files which are open to the public, hence the name.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to symlink the storage from the public directory.

> To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a
> symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. Utilizing
> this folder convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one
> directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero
> down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan
> command:

Answer (score -1):

as alternative,
let laravel set the file stored in `/storage/app` folder.

if we want to read the file, just use like `$publicPath = '../storage/app/'.$path;`