# Laravel: Storage not putting file inside public folder

Tags: php, laravel

When I use:

```
Storage::putFile('documents', $content, 'public');
```

I expect the folder structure inside public directory, like:

```
+
+-- storage
+--|-- app
+--|--|-- public
+--|--|--|-- documents
+--|--|--|--|-- XyZ.pdf
+
```

Instead of:

```
+
+-- storage
+--|-- app
+--|--|-- documents
+--|--|--|-- XyZ.pdf
+--|--|-- public
+
```

So, to force storage at "right" place I need to explicit put:

```
Storage::putFile('public/documents', $content, 'public');
```

What returns me a path that I'm not able to save at database because its values is `"public/documents/xyz.pdf"` and will not work properly with `asset()` helper.

How to use `Storage` facade to put files inside `storage/app/public`?

Comment: `Storage::put(public_path('documents'), ... );` ?

Comment: You can try this answer given here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44577640/8776138

Comment: @CyRossignol nope. `public_path()` returns an absolute path to `./public` root folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't explicity in the docs.

Looking at `config/filesystems.php`, we have a `public` disk. Just use it:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('documents', $content);
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you were trying to do now. By the way, [here are the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/filesystem#the-public-disk).

Comment: As an addition to the above, using the putFileAs() method, allows you to specify the filename which is convenient if you have some file naming conventions. For example:

  `Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($location, $file, $fileName, 'public'); `

Comment: Was running into this exact same problem. The docs are plain wrong. Laravel really drops the ball by trying to keep their docs so simple and clean and ignoring so many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants every file to be stored in public and also wishes framework to magically handle the storage location is by using `.env` files. Open your .env file and you will find following line

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
```

Change the value to `public`

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

Now all your storage method will by default store all files inside `storage/app/public` directory. Regardless of methods you use

```
Storage::store
Storage::storeAs
Storage::put
Storage::putFileAs
$request->file('avatar')->storeAs
```

**Note:** If there's anything you want to store locally (inside non-public directory), then you have to mention the disk as

```
Storage::disk('local')
```