# Laravel 6 Storage results in a 404 error when trying to fetch files

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have tried to setup an upload script in Laravel and have followed the instructions in the docs.
I created a Symlink using the Laravel script and it looks like the following

> storage -> /Users/username/Sites/switch/storage/app/public

The problem arrives when I go to upload the image and then get result of the image url in return. As you can see to match the symlink I set the folder to be public below.

```
$path = $request->file('manufacturer_image_name')->store('public');
echo asset($path);
```

and this returns

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/XxIX7L75cLZ7cf2xzejc3E6STrcjfeeu3AQcSKz1.png

the problem is this doesn't work and throws a 404 but if I manually change the url from "public" to "storage" it will find the image.

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/XxIX7L75cLZ7cf2xzejc3E6STrcjfeeu3AQcSKz1.png

Shouldn't

> echo asset($path);

be returning a url containing storage instead of public?

Comment: what is the value of `$path` itself?

Comment: In the above example path returns http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/XxIX7L75cLZ7cf2xzejc3E6STrcjfeeu3AQcSKz1.png

Comment: no ... just `$path` not `asset($path)`

Comment: That returns public/XxIX7L75cLZ7cf2xzejc3E6STrcjfeeu3AQcSKz1.png

Comment: what are you using as the default disk?  because you are telling it to save the file in a folder named `public` not a disk named `public`

Comment: Im using the default setup   'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: that is what you have set as the default currently? the `public` disk?

Comment: yeah not touched these settings

Answer (score 3):

`assett($path)` is for generating a URL for assets that are just in the public folder, things like the Mix generated CSS and JS files. If you user Laravel Storage to save the file, you also have to use Laravel storage to generate the file URL.

```
Storage::url('file.jpg');
```

Comment: if they were using the `public` disk this would work out better, but the local disk doesn't generate URLs

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a lot of ways to do that, pick anyone which fits you best.

```
// using storage_path helper
storage_path('public/' . $filename);

// you could make a double-check with File::exist() method
$path = storage_path('public/' . $filename);

if (!File::exists($path)) {
   abort(404);
}

// using asset helper
asset('storage/your_folder/image.png');

// using url helper
url('storage/your_folder/image.png');

// using Storage facade
Storage::url($photoLink)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest and exact thing for your issue

```
            if(!empty($request->file('manufacturer_image_name'))){
                $path = storage_path('public/image/');

                $image_path = Storage::disk('public')->put('manufacturer_image_name', $request->file('manufacturer_image_name'));

                //Assuming you have a model called Manufacturer and created $manufacturer = new Manufacturer()  
               $manufacturer->manufacturer_image_name = isset($image_path) ?  "storage/".$image_path : "";
            }
```

Comment: there's no need to manually create directories and even if you have to you should never give 777 permission to directories

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I discovered this answer the fits nearly perfectly what I am after. [Laravel: Storage not putting file inside public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513546/laravel-storage-not-putting-file-inside-public-folder)

This was what I ended up with.

```
if($request->file('manufacturer_image_name')){

                $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('logo', $request->file('manufacturer_image_name'));

                echo $path;

                }
```

$path now returns "logo/filename.ext" instead of "public/ or storage/" so I can store this directly in the db.

Comment: just out of curiosity, in your orginal question us said manually changing public to storage worked. Just wanted to confirm, is it only storage or storage/public, http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/X.. OR http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/X.. that worked for you?

Comment: its because you were telling the file to be stored in a folder named `public` off the root of the disk (local disk), so it gives you back that exact path from the root of the disk : `public/xxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Originally I found that if I simply changed http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/XxIX7L75cLZ7cf2xzejc3E6STrcjfeeu3AQcSKz1.png to http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/XxIX7L75cLZ7cf2xzejc3E6STrcjfeeu3AQcSKz1.png it would work.