# How to upload video using file button?

Tags: laravel

I,ve been trying to upload a video via the file button but i'm not sure how to save the file to the public folder.

This is my code in the controller:

```
    if($request->hasFile('videofile')){

        $video=$request->file('videofile');
        $filename=time() . '.' . $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filenamesave=File::save(public_path('videos/'.$filename));
    }

    $link=new videos();
    $link->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
    $link->video=$filename;
    $link->save();
```

I'm getting this error:

Method save() doesn't exist

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577380/how-to-upload-files-in-laravel-directly-into-public-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Receive Video File

```
$video = $request->file('videofile');
```

Create Folders "/uploads/video/" inside your public folder.

```
  if($request->hasFile('videofile')){
        $video = $request->file('video');
        $video_name =date("j-M-Y").'.'.time().$video->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/video/');
        $video->move($destinationPath, $video_name);
        $save_path =  '/uploads/video/';
        $filename = $save_path.$video_name; 
    }
```

Save your new link to database.

```
$link=new videos();
$link->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
$link->video=$filename;
$link->save();
```

And Use this link with asset() method. like, 
`asset($data->video)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `File::save()` does not exists, instead use `put()`. You check the documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances