# Laravel - pass GET requests to files through controller

Tags: php, laravel, http-get, laravel-5.6

In my laravel App I want to validate if the client has a cookie before redirecting he/she to the actual file. For this I've created a controller function to receive this new route I created:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']], function(){
   Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'HomeController@getArquivo');
}
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

 public function getArquivo($filename)
 {
    if(hasCookie()) Redirect::to('/storage/' . $filename);
    else Redirect::to('/some/other/address');
 }
}
```

So, for example, in my storage I have a file called `8-0.jpeg` and the `getArquivo` function is only called when I pass a filename different of it (like url.com/storage/something). If I pass the exact filename url.com/storage/8-0.jpeg) then it just returns the image ignoring the route. So my question is, how to force the GET request to always pass through this controller first? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I've made changes according to the answers provided yet I can't get it to work. How the code is now:

Middleware:

```
class VerificaCookieArquivo
{
var $nomeBiscoitoSessao = "biscoito";
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->temBiscoito()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return Redirect::to('/some/other/address');
}

private function temBiscoito(){
    return isset($_COOKIE[$this->nomeBiscoitoSessao]);
}

}
```

`Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //other middlewares
    'verificaCookieArquivo' => \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\VerificaCookieArquivo::class,
];
```

In the routes (`web.php`) I've created a separated route group for this cookie check since I don't want it to impact on the other routes I have:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['verificaCookieArquivo']], function()
{
    Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'HomeController@getArquivo');   

});
```

In HomeController.php:

```
public function getArquivo($filename){
    $fullpath = "/storage/" . $filename;
    return response()->download(storage_path($fullpath), null, [], null);
}
```

Still can't get it to work, the behavior still the same as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a middleware that will check a visiter with valid cookie. You can create it like this

Middleware class

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class SecureFile
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->hasCookie()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/some/other/address');
    }

    private function hasCookie(){
        //check cookie here and return ture or false 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now add this `SecureFile` middleware to `routeMiddleware` in Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    ...
    'secureFile' => \App\Http\Middleware\SecureFile::class,
];
```

Final step use this middleware to your route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web','secureFile']], function(){
   Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'HomeController@getArquivo');
}
```

And in controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

     public function getArquivo($filename)
     {
        $fullpath = "any_sub_folder/" . $filename;
        return response()->download(storage_path($fullpath), null, [], null);
        //https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads
     }
}
```

**EDIT**
It seems you have images in `public/storage` folder then your image will be loaded directly, it will not call your route. Try placing your images in `storage` folder and add different route like this

```
Route::get('file/{filename}', 'HomeController@getArquivo')->middleware('secureFile');
```

Comment: that didn't worked, I also had to put the `route::get` to this controller in a different middleware group that `web` because it was messing with the other routes that I don't want to verify this cookie

Comment: create a separate route group that need to need to check cookie. If this is the only then create separate route for it

Comment: still can't get it to work, I've updated my question with the new code I've wrote

Comment: you have storage folder inside public folder ? if you have storage folder inside public folder and all your images inside it then all these images are public accessible. There is no use of protecting those image

Comment: you are confused about `storage` folder,  `storage_path` return `laravel_root_folder/storage` not `public/storage` folder. Any files inside public folders are publicly available. Better store your private images (that need cookie) in `laravel_root_folder/storage` folder and then try my answer it will work

Comment: I understand, yet's not working. I've tried a lot of combinations but still nothing

Comment: did you debug, does your request reached to `temBiscoito` function ?

Comment: yes I did. The function is only reached when I type an url with a filename that doesn't exist in the storage. If the file exists, it just gives the file to the user ignoring the middleware

Comment: Do you have file inside ‘public/storage’ folder? if it is there then it will be publickly accessible, that means your route will not called. Check it, does your route is called when you have file?

Comment: yes, the files are inside (considering / as the root of the laravel project) /public/storage. Not inside the /storage folder

Comment: ah, thats the reason. It will not call you route. Place all your protected files inside ‘storage’ folder and change your route.

Comment: well I was afraid that the solution was that. I remember last year I had to put all files in the public directory because I was having a problem with the server I was running, I even made a question about this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577380/how-to-upload-files-in-laravel-directly-into-public-folder). But I don't understad why it doesn't call the route, afterall it is just a HTTP GET call to a file in the server, shouldn't I be able to control it just like I control requests to page files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176519/discussion-between-rkj-and-fabiotk).

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware in LAravel with:

```
php artisan make:middleware CookieCheck
```

Add this middleware into `Kernel.php` file

add these middleware to route:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web','cookie:check']], function(){
   Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'HomeController@getArquivo');
}
```

Put Cookie check code into Middleware.