# How to save images in public_html instead of the default storage in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Laravel shared hosting saving images problem:**

**Situation:**

- Can't create symlink() `"symlink() has been disabled for security
  reasons"`
- no ssh support just ftp

**How to save images to `public_html` lets say to a file `storage/cover_image`**

*This was the shortcut generated during development*

```
if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
       Storage::disk('my_upload')->put($fileNameToStore, $request->file('cover_image'));
            //$path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
```

I made a custom disk in called `my_upload` i cant figure out where it saves the file but it doesn't save in `public_html/storage/cover_images`

```
//custom my_disk code
'my_upload' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/storage/cover_images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

if i use storeAs it always stores `storage` that is not in `public_html` its also not an issue with permissions since am still testing i have set the permissions to `777`

Comment: Just a short tip. Don’t use hosting providers like you are using, just rent a VPS through someone like digitalocean, and have full control

Comment: now i know better

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: yeah its a shared hosting

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are on shared hosting, what I know most hosting providers has their rules to php.ini configurations cmiiw.

So, if you want put your image on public_html, you can do like this:

```
$path = '/home/{your_shared_hosting_username}/public_html/cover_image';
$request->file('cover_image')->move($path, $filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

After hours of research and grinding solved my problem eventually... to help other me's.

**Step 1:**

Create a custom disk in `config/filesystem.php`

```
//In my case
'my_upload' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

**Step 2:**

Change `public_path()` to `public_html`

```
//What worked for me 
//Changed file: public_html/index.php 
//after bootstrap declaration-> this is important

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

**Step 3:**

Now save your file like this

```
// Handle File Upload
       if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
           // Get filename with the extension
           $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
           // Get just filename
           $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
           // Get just ext
           $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
           // Filename to store
           $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
           // Upload Image
          $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('cover_images', $fileNameToStore,['disk' => 'my_upload']);
       if(!$path){
               return false;

               }

       } else {
           $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
       }
```

In my case my images will be saved in `public_html/storage/cover_images`

**Resources:**

[How to upload files in Laravel directly into public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577380/how-to-upload-files-in-laravel-directly-into-public-folder)

However that doesn't cut it since images are stored in the laravel `public` so you have to change the default laravel public to your now `public_html` which is your public in shared hosting.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5

> Tested on laravel 5.8

**NB:** I also noted running laravel `config:cache` breaks the saving location..you should probably avoid this command.

Incase you already ran the command `config:clear` undo's