# laravel file upload tmp file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Hello guys when I use file upload and save link in database it save this "/tmp/phpkPhygr|public/allFiles/files/26657d5ff9020d2abefe558796b99584/69adc1e107f7f7d035d7baf04342e1ca.gif" so why "tmp/php..." show in this link or I want to remove this to work this url.

```
        $files = array();
    if($files = $request->file('files')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $fileName = md5(rand(100,1000)) . "." . strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $folder='public/allFiles/files/' . md5(rand(100,10));
            $file_url = $folder . "/" . $fileName;
            $file->move($folder, $fileName);
            $files[] = $file_url;
        }
    }
    $filesReq = $files;
    if($filesReq == ' '){
        $filesReq = 'no files';
    }else{
        $filesReq = implode('|', $files);
    }
```

Comment: file has moved or not?

Comment: yes moved but url send to database as /tmp/phpkPhygr/........gif so when i want to export url from database link not working

Comment: try to add ```$file_url = $folder . "/" . $fileName;```  after ```$file->move($folder, $fileName);``` and tell me what happened

Comment: same thing can see this dd 

  -test: false
  -originalName: "38a7f861d2c6e5624db27fd3ea086876.gif"
  -mimeType: "image/gif"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpI3chl2"
  basename: "phpI3chl2"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpI3chl2"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpI3chl2"
  aTime: 2022-05-24 14:31:09
  mTime: 2022-05-24 14:31:09
  cTime: 2022-05-24 14:31:09
  inode: 24719
  size: 935511
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1163
  group: 1164
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false

Comment: pathname: "/tmp/phpI3chl2

Comment: you are get the file path from memory, this problem cuze you are trying to get the file path before save your file, the get the path from memory
so you can search how to fix it but you are using move() its not bets
and you must save you uploded files in storage not publuc
,,
so you can use ```$file->store('your path', ['disk' => 'public']);``` 

if it desn't work just see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44577640/10334589

and tell me what happened